# IIS 10 Crashes when opening URL Rewrite Feature?

Tags: iis-10

I have IIS 10 on Windows. Everything used to work fine. Today when double clicking the icon **URL Rewrite**, IIS 10 crashes.

I tried that even with a new empty website that has no rules.

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Do you have any pending Windows updates? Did you try restarting the machine?

Comment: @MichaelZ. I have restarted the machine indeed and no pending updates actually.

Comment: IIS Manager is .NET application itself, so you can debug what crashed it using a debugger and find out the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution :

run

```
%windir%\System32\Inetsrv\InetMgr.exe /reset
```

Source : https://forums.iis.net/t/1160660.aspx